# Android ExposedDropdownMenu endIconDrawable without a flicker on interact

Tags: android, material-design, autocompletetextview, android-textinputlayout, exposeddropdownmenu

The endIconDrawable, as shown in other posts on StackOverflow, can be overwritten through the usage of app:endIconDrawable attribute on a Material2 AutoCompleteTextView xml view element.

My inquiry is if it is possible to prevent the default behavior of an exposeddropdownmenu using autocompletetextview where the endIcon changes between state_checked true and false states, because there is a brief flicker when the icon sees a state change when interacting with the textview. I have one icon drawable that I want to be the same for both state_checked true and false, and **while I do have this now and functioning**, the flicker between the same icon asset, if I can prevent that, would be much cleaner and nicer looking.

How can I go about achieving this?